# How to add a hostname for my router's IP address?

Tags: macos, network, router

How can I access the WiFi router I am currently connected to via an unchanging hostname?

For command-line stuff like ping, or http in the browser to load the router's settings page.

The hostname should always point at whatever the current router's IP address is, as can be found manually by going to System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > TCP/IP

[image]

I would like `http://myrouter` in Safari to do the same thing as visiting `http://192.168.0.1` in this case. Maybe sometimes I will be connected to another wifi network where the router's IP is different, in that case I still want to be able to simply visit `http://myrouter` but this time get redirected to/shown `http://192.168.1.2` for example.

Does this kind of hostname already exist? If not, how can I set that up?

Comment: If your router allows you to edit the DHCP/DNS info on your router you may be able to add a name there, but I don't believe that is possible as naming things on a network is done with a DNS server. And on an edge device (Mac, PC, iOS, etc) done with the hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the way it works.

Your Mac is a client on the network(s) you attatch to  and it gets its settings from from the DHCP server.  In that DHCP response, theres a number of things including a DNS server assignment(s) which is where all the names on the network come from.  Those name to address relationships are ultimately managed by the network admin.

Your client can’t arbitrarily assign names to IP addresses as your Mac is not the DNS server.

The `/etc/hosts` file is for you and you alone and must be manually updated (if necessary) when you change networks because there is nothing that’s mapping the actual router address to the name you’ve arbitrarily given it.

Comment: Why must it be manually updated? Can't I automate new network location detected to updating that file?

Comment: You can automate the manual process

Comment: To what end?  I do this for a living and have never needed to have a dns entry for an internet gateway

Comment: Next question, for which interface?  Multihomed networks often don’t connect to the same network, so there will be multiple routers.  So, how do you want to differentiate the two?

Comment: @Allan always wifi, and the purpose is to get into router configuration pages, public network "join" pages, ssh into my homes' routers, or (equivalently I guess) ssh into robot devices (got some robots providing their own wifi networks)